# Setting the optimal thresholds for a multiclass random forest and gbt model in pyspark (ml) on an imbalanced dataset

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml, adaptive-threshold

Currently a Random Forest Classifier (from Spark ML) has been build on a imbalanced dataset which has the following distribution:

```
+-------+----------------+
| score | n_observations |
+-------+----------------+
|     0 |         256741 |
|     1 |          13913 |
|     2 |           7632 |
|     3 |          15877 |
|     4 |           3289 |
|     5 |          11515 |
|     6 |           8555 |
|     7 |           2087 |
|     8 |          14226 |
|     9 |           6379 |
+-------+----------------+
```

As an outcome from a multiclass problem I get the following probability matrix. The probability column gives the probability of an observation being classified as a class. (these are the normalized rawPredicitions from the Random Forest model).

```
+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| observation_number | label_score | prob_0  | prob_1  | prob_2  | prob_3  | prob_4  | prob_5  | prob_6  | prob_7  | prob_8  | prob_9  |
+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|                  0 |           0 |  0,812  |  0,039  |  0,024  |  0,049  |  0,007  |  0,024  |  0,019  |  0,002  |  0,016  |  0,008  |
|                  1 |           7 |  0,419  |  0,050  |  0,032  |  0,092  |  0,018  |  0,083  |  0,080  |  0,013  |  0,132  |  0,082  |
|                  2 |           0 |  0,862  |  0,027  |  0,017  |  0,043  |  0,004  |  0,016  |  0,015  |  0,001  |  0,009  |  0,006  |
|                  3 |           0 |  0,845  |  0,028  |  0,018  |  0,049  |  0,004  |  0,018  |  0,018  |  0,001  |  0,011  |  0,008  |
|                  4 |           6 |  0,445  |  0,051  |  0,034  |  0,095  |  0,017  |  0,080  |  0,079  |  0,012  |  0,115  |  0,073  |
+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The actual predictions classes are highly skewed towards the majority classes (0 & 8). This is due to the fact that the majority probability is used to assign a class to an observation as can be seen below. Applying an undersampling and an oversampling method does not increase the accuracy of the output from the confusion matrix.

[Confusion matrix from the output, also put into table form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17dpV.png)

However, using these predictions the AUC curves seem quite promising. (average AUC of 0.74). See the plot of the one to many AUC curve per class below:

[AUC curves for the different classes (one-to-many)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h57uQ.png)

I am unsure how to retrieve the optimal class from these probabilities. Looking at the AUC there are multiple ways to get the optimal threshold. A solution would be to multiply with the inverse of the prior probability, whilst another would be to fit a linear regression. Another solution could be the pairwise analysis as explained in this paper, however I am not sure how to apply there algorithm precisely. [Approximating the multiclass ROC by pairwise analysis](https://homepage.tudelft.nl/a9p19/papers/prl_07_roc.pdf)

What would be the easiest Spark implementation to obtain some class weighing on the predicted probabilities for the Random Forest (or other tree classifiers)?